# Get 404 http error with WEB-INF/views/index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, model-view-controller

I created simple Spring MVC project from an example but it doesn't work. I use Tomcat and it doesn't see my `index.jsp` in **WEB-INF/views/** package and I get 404 error. But if I put **index.jsp** into **webapp** package, Tomcat will find it. That's my configuration and classes:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbvzY.png)

**web.xml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mihusle" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**MainController:**

```
package com.mihusle.controller;

import com.mihusle.model.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * Created by MHSL on 17.06.2017.
 */
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView main() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("userJSP", new User());
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check-user")
    public ModelAndView checkUser(@ModelAttribute("userJSP") User user) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("secondPage");
        modelAndView.addObject("userJSP", user);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**User:**

```
package com.mihusle.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Created by MHSL on 17.06.2017.
 */
@Component
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**index.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<body>
<spring:form method="post"  modelAttribute="userJSP" action="check-user">

    Name: <spring:input path="name"/> (path="" - указывает путь, используемый в modelAttribute=''. в нашем случае User.name)  <br/>
    Password: <spring:input path="password"/>   <br/>
    <spring:button>Next Page</spring:button>

</spring:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. I spent all day trying to find the solution but now I have no assumptions what problem may be here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should configure your welcome pages in `web.xml`.

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Second, **never, ever**, put `jsp` or `html` pages under the `WEB-INF` folder. It is meant for containing files that clients won't be able to access.